# How To Limit Scraped Image In Python

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, limit, reddit

**Code**

It's Open Source so no need to hide anything
And I am New To It

```
    #reddit-scraper
print("Reddit scraper")

import praw
import wget
import os
import datetime

#getting user inputs
subreddit_input = "meme"#input("Enter subreddit: /r/")
x = "hot"#input("Enter sort order (hot, new, top): ")
image_number = int(10)#input("Enter the number of submissions to parse (limit 1000): "))
limits=int(1)

#renaming
#Rename= range(1,10);

#initializing PRAW things
reddit = praw.Reddit('main_account', user_agent='main_account user agent') #this logs into a reddit account specified in praw.ini
subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subreddit_input)

if x == "hot":
    sort_order = subreddit.hot
elif x == "new":
    sort_order = subreddit.new
elif x == "top":
    sort_order = subreddit.top

for submission in sort_order (limit=image_number):


    
    #this changes datetime to display time with . instead of : because : cannot be used in filenames
    date_and_time = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(submission.created))
    date_time_list = list(date_and_time)
    date_time_list[13] = "."
    date_time_list[16] = "."
    date_and_time_string = "".join(date_time_list)

    #this gets the reddit submission's title and the file extension of the submission's link
    Instapy = str(submission.title)
    print(submission.title, submission.url)
    file_extension = submission.url[len(submission.url) -4:]

    if file_extension == ".jpg" : #if url is a direct image link
        

        #if submission title includes character not usable in filename:
        if ("?" in str(Instapy) 
        or "/"  in str(Instapy)
        or "\\" in str(Instapy)
        or ":" in str(Instapy)
        or "*" in str(Instapy)
        or "\"" in str(Instapy)
        or "<" in str(Instapy)
        or ">" in str(Instapy)
        or "|" in str(Instapy)):

            #change illegal character
            Instapy = Instapy.replace("?", "&#63")
            Instapy = Instapy.replace("/", "&#47")
            Instapy = Instapy.replace("\\", "&#92")
            Instapy = Instapy.replace(":", "&#58")
            Instapy = Instapy.replace("\"", "&#92")
            Instapy = Instapy.replace("<", "&#60")
            Instapy = Instapy.replace(">", "&#62")
            Instapy = Instapy.replace("|", "&#124")
            Instapy = Instapy.replace("*", "&#42")

        if os.path.exists("/home/user/Desktop/INSTA/Images/" + date_and_time_string + " - " + Instapy + file_extension) == False:
            
            if file_extension == ".jpg":
                file_name = wget.download(submission.url,)
                os.rename(file_name, "/home/user/Desktop/INSTA/Images/" "hello" + " .jpg")
                
                

            print("\n")

        else:
            print("File already downloaded.\n")

    else:
        print("Submission is not a direct image link.")
```

**Where I Want To Implement**

I want the obtained  image in another program that uses a specific filename, filetype, and Folder like hello.jpg in /Desktop/EXAMPLE/IMAGES/hello.jpg

**What I Get**

I get the same result but instead, the program overwrites the downloaded file which means I get a different image same name

**Expectations**

Either I want then naming structure to be like image,image1,image2 or it should stop after
downloading 1st image

**Help**

I am new to python and have very less experience it any other suggestions regarding the code might be a great help to me

Thank You